# What do the files in bitcoin/src/rpc/ do?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-core-development, p2p

I know that RPC stands for Remote Procedure Call. Does Bitcoin Core do RPCs with other nodes on the network?

Answer (score 3):

No, Bitcoin Core speaks the [Bitcoin P2P protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation) with other nodes.

The RPC interface is specific to the Bitcoin Core software, and for communication with the (human) operator of the software (through the `bitcoin-cli` tool), or for other (local) software to interact with (e.g. instructing it to create addresses, send funds, compute statistics, ...). The same commands can also be given in the Debug window in `bitcoin-qt`.

You can find documentation about the various supported RPC calls on https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/.

Comment: Why aren't these called 'Commands', rather than RPC's? You would think that they would more closely resemble commands to the system. I don't know much about RPC's, but why are they called RPC's?

Comment: Probably because initially they were primarily intended for interaction with other software, possibly running on other machines, than for interaction with people. They do use a communication protocol called JSON-RPC (see jsonrpc.org), which may have inspired the name. What's in a name?

Comment: Are these [link]https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/ all the possible commands which can be entered into the bitcoin-cli, or are there more?

Comment: The website lists all documented RPC calls (up to version 24.0; it's not updated for 25.0 yet, though I don't think that much changed). There are a few undocumented RPC calls that are only intended for testing purposes; those are not listed on the website either.